# Seg Faults and Instantiation Errors while running PyQGIS on OS X

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm having issues getting off the ground with running PyQGIS on my OS X. I'm frankly very confused as some errors occur sporadically while executing the same code.

When I try the following:

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS', True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()
```

I either get one of three scenarios:

- Segmentation fault: 11 when returning the list
- A blank list returned
- Or a this error after initQgis()...

  QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
  QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

A workaround I found to work is to instantiate a QgsApplication object first as the error suggests with something like

```
app = QgsApplication([], True)
```

However, the problem here is that this creates a GUI which I don't need - I'm just trying to do some scripting. If I change the instantiation parameter to False, then I get an error with initQgis() of:

```
QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used
```

Also, in a lot of examples I've found online you don't need the instantiation step... is there something funky with my setup?

I'm using a venv if that makes any difference... all commands I want to run work normally in the QGIS Python console, it's just the external script that's giving me issues.

Any thoughts?

Python: 2.7.10,
QGIS: 2.10.1-Pisa,
OS X: 10.10.3

Answer (score 2):

I had also some troubles with this, here is my solution for OSX 10.9.5:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGis.app/Contents/Resources/python')
from qgis.core import *

app = QgsApplication([],True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

layer = QgsVectorLayer('/tmp/myshape.shp', 'test', 'ogr')
print layer.isValid()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add first `Applications/Qgis.app/Contents/Resources/python` to the PYTHONPATH

First solution outside Python

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/Qgis.app/Contents/Resources/python
# then 
python
....
#Import QGIS
from qgis.core import *
```

Second solution in Python

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGis.app/Contents/Resources/python')
#Import QGIS
from qgis.core import *
```

In both cases you need to initialize the app (otherwise crash)

```
app = QgsApplication([],True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Plugins", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

You can now use PyQGIS

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer('/Users/Shared/test.shp', 'test', 'ogr')
layer.isValid()
True
```

In the same way you can add the path of the plugins to sys, use the processing algorithms and...

Comment: _export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/Qgis.app/Contents/Resources/Python_ should be **python** with lowercase p in Python